# Selecting objects from a list with jq based on a value, accessing the top-level object

Tags: json, jq

So I have a structure like this:

```
[
{
  "name": "aaaaa",
  "type": "A",
  "class": "IN",
  "status": "NOERROR",
  "data": {
    "answers": [
      {
        "ttl": 30,
        "type": "CNAME",
        "class": "IN",
        "name": "aaaaa",
        "data": "bbbbb"
      },
      {
        "ttl": 1800,
        "type": "CNAME",
        "class": "IN",
        "name": "bbbbb",
        "data": "ccccc"
      },
      {
        "ttl": 60,
        "type": "A",
        "class": "IN",
        "name": "ccccc",
        "data": "1.2.3.4"
      }
    ],
},
{
  "name": ...
...
```

It's basically a list of DNS resolution data.

For each question, there may be more than one answer. All I care about the is `type: "A"` record.  After a little work and reading, I came up with this:

```
. | select(
    (.status = "NOERROR") and
    (.class = "IN") and
    (.data.answers? != null)) | select(.data.answers | map(select(.type == "A")))
```

This works to give me only the objects where the type is "A". However, because of the way that I built it, I lose the top level "name" value. The only thing returned are the actual `answer` objects themselves, the objects in the `answers[]`

The problem is, I need to access the original (top-level) name value. I'm missing something simple here, can someone give me a hand?

Thanks

EDIT: What I want to print out at the end is basically the top-level `.name` value and each `.data` value where the `type == "A"`. There's a probably a much simpler way to do this, so if there is a completely different approach, I'm happy to hear that as well!

EDIT2: I originally thought this would be simpler and did:

```
. | select(
  (.status = "NOERROR") and
  (.class = "IN") and
  (.data.answers? != null) and
  (.data.answers[].type=="A")) | .
```

... but this returns the entire list of `A`, `CNAME`, and other types of values, as long as there is a single `A` present, it seems. So no luck there

Comment: The answer from @oguz ismail worked, I just had to change the `.[]` to `.` or I got string index errors. Probably due to me not clearly representing the data structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, because of the way that I built it, I lose the top level "name" value

Stay in the top-level then.

```
.[]
| select(.class == "IN" and .status == "NOERROR")
| .name + ": " + (.data.answers[] | select(.type == "A") .data)?
```